# Website Development: How to make the text/image emerge when a user click on the another text/image?

Tags: html

How to make the text/image emerge when you click on the another text/image? For example, a bottom "help" on the top of this website makes appear the image and the text when you click on it. I'm trying to do the same effect with my personal website. Anybody know the way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the JavaScript onClick(); event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp.

Set your the element that you want to show to display:none; then set to display:block; onclick or even use the jQuery fadeIn effect.

I'm not entirely too sure what you're after, but I hope that this is a start.

Set an ID to the element (like ). In your CSS stylesheet, simply add the following:

```
#hideMe { display:none; }
```

Comment: Thanks James, but I dont know how to set the element to "display:none" and for what i need "display:block". Could you please give me a example or referance.